# Skipping certain items when parsing an array of json objects with Aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

I am trying to write a `FromJSON` implementation which would parse a list of objects while at the same time skipping some of them - those which contain a certain json property.

I have the code like this, but without proper handling of mzero it returns an error once it encounters a value with "exclude: true".

```hs
newtype Response = Response [Foo]
newtype Foo = Foo Text

instance FromJSON Response where
  parseJSON = withArray "Foos" $ \arr -> do
    -- can I filter out here the ones which return `mzero`?
    foos <- mapM parseJSON arr
    pure $ Response (toList foos)

instance FromJSON Foo where
  parseJSON = withObject "Foo" $ \foo -> do
    isExcluded <- foo .: "exclude"
    if isExcluded
      then mzero
      else do
        pure $ Foo "bar"
```

I've found a few questions which hint at using `parseMaybe`, but I can't figure out how I can use it from within the `FromJSON` definition, it seems to be more suited to running the parser from "outside". Is it possible to do skipping "inside"? Or am I going the wrong route here?

Comment: Consider the [optional](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:optional) function, which, in your case, will have the type `Parser a -> Parser (Maybe a)`.  Perhaps this could be used in conjunction with something like `catMaybes` to do what you want.

Comment: @DDub thank you that was exactly what I needed! Can you please post this as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [optional](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:optional) function.  It can be a bit tricky to find because it's very general-purpose and not simply a helper function in `aeson`.  For your purposes, it will have the type `Parser a -> Parser (Maybe a)` and used in conjunction with `catMaybes` should do what you want.